# Metamask connection with private node with rpc

Tags: metamask

i am trying to connect metamask with private node but its fails to connect

geth --rpc --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,ssh,tapool,personal,web3 --datadir NODEDATA --networkid 123456 console

Comment: How do you connect it? Are they on the same machine?

Comment: tell me about both same machine and different machine with metamask

Answer (score 0):

on the same machine use `--rpcaddr 127.0.0.1` to start the JSON RCP on the localhost network and only connections from your local machine reach the geth server

on a remote machine use `--rpcaddr "0.0.0.0"` to allow remote connections.

For both case in metamask indicate the machine ip (for the first case use http://127.0.0.1:8545 for the second case use the machine ip instead 127.0.0.1)

Comment: its not connecting i have given --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" if give the ip it shows error Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen tcp ip:8545: bind: cannot assign requested address

Comment: Maybe another process is using that port try to use lsof -i :8545 to see if which process is listening

Comment: i have checked no other process is using port 8545

Comment: change 0.0.0.0 by its public ip

Comment: sir still not connected i have written --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0

Comment: describe how do you try to connect

Comment: geth --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,ssh,tapool,personal,web3 --datadir NODEDATA --networkid 123456 console

Comment: i execute this command console is open after that i try to connect with metamask with custom rpc and there i give the url of http://ip:8545